# PowerShell Script return null value when integrate with c#

Tags: powershell

When i run PowerShell script in PowerShell ISE it gives me proper output but when i integrate my PowerShell script with C# then it gives me Null value

```
$filter = "Revit 2014";

$uninstallKey =  "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

$uninstallData = (Get-ChildItem $uninstallKey).Name | % { $path = "Registry::$_"; Get-ItemProperty $path } 

$getGuid = $uninstallData | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like $filter } | Select-Object -Property PsChildName

$guid = $($getGuid.PSChildName)

if($guid -ne $null)
{
    return $guid
}
else
{
    return "Guid is Null"
}
```

```
 Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

 runspace.Open();

 Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
 pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

 Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

 runspace.Close();

 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 foreach (PSObject obj in results)
 {
       stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
 }

 return stringBuilder.ToString();
```

When run integrating with C#
Expected Output :- return $guid

Actual Output :- Guid is Null

but When i run script in PowerShell ISE output is it return $guid as expected

Comment: What is output of `[System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess` in PowerShell ISE and `System.Environment.Is64BitProcess` in your C# application.

Comment: @PetSerAl output of [System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess in PowerShell ISE is True and output of System.Environment.Is64BitProcess in your C# application is False

Comment: Since your app is 32-bit, it run 32-bit PowerShell, thus it access 32-bit view of registry. While PowerShell ISE access 64-bit view of registry. Thus them get different results.